# why this addEventListener not working for the li element I create?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I try to implement an aotocomplete input. I want when user clicked new added li element, the input value will be the value of the li element. However, this addEventListener seems not work in this function. May I know why? I think every new li element did create before I add event listener to them.

```
function displayMatches(matchesArr) {
  var newLi;
  for (let j of matchesArr) {
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = `<li id="${j.replace(/\s/g,'')}">${j}</li>`;
    autoResults.innerHTML += newLi.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(j.replace(/\s/g, '')).addEventListener("click",
      function(e) {
        alert("Hello World!");
      })
  }
}
```

If I use NewLi it also doesn't work.

```
newLi.addEventListener("click", 
    function(e) {
        alert("Hello World!");
    })
```

Comment: Do you really want to put an LI inside another LI?

Comment: @Ying I have deleted my answer, as it was incorrect. Good Luck!

Comment: Hello! No I want to add li to an ul which is already in html <div class="container">
  <form>
    <input id="autocompleteInput" name="autocompleteInput" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
  </form>
  <ul id="autocompleteResults"></ul>
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` that you're adding to the DOM is not the same one as `newLi`. You're creating a brand new element when you assign to `.innerHTML`. You're also destroying and recreating all the old elements in `autoResults`. When you assign to `.innerHTML` it parses the HTML text from scratch, creating all new elements; any properties that were set on the old elements, such as event listeners, are lost.

Instead of assigning to `.innerHTML`, append the element itself.

```js
function displayMatches(matchesArr) {
  var newLi;
  for (let j of matchesArr) {
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.id = j.replace(/\s/g, '');
    newLi.innerHTML = j;
    newLi.addEventListener("click",
      function(e) {
        alert("Hello World!");
      });
    autoResults.appendChild(newLi);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! So the problem is this line "autoResults.innerHTML += newLi.innerHTML;" right? When we assign something to an element's innerHTML, everything we assign to this element before will lost?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote.